# Indication of privileges via colors in terminal?

Tags: linux, centos

I wanted to configure terminal settings in CentOS7 in such a way, that whenever users works or switches to root user account. The terminal text should be displayed in RED color (which is an indication to the user to be more careful for an user on what he is executing). And for all other normal user accounts, the terminal text should be in green color. Is this achievable ?

Comment: They shouldn't switch to the root account. They should be using `sudo` for every single command they need to run as root. That way you would be able to keep track of who did what, and when.  This is obviously my personal opinion though.  The root account should already be set up with a significantly different prompt, exactly for this reason.  Traditionally, a `#` prompt is used for root.

Comment: Yep you are absolutely right. I just thought of adding one more indication as the color has little more precedence than the text. And obviously our goal is to enable only sudo rights but at this point of time, its not done but soon we need to work on it. Now only administrators have the direct root access (which is not a good idea though).

Comment: Setting up a simple sudo configuration should take a few minutes. Most distros will give full sudo privileges to anyone in group `sudo`/`wheel` depending on discro.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comments above with respect to using `sudo` over logging in as root.  That said, here's a variation of something from `/etc/bash/bashrc` on my Gentoo box that I think does what you want:

```
if [[ "$(id -u)" == "0" ]] ; then
    PS1+='\[\033[01;31m\]\h\[\033[01;36m\] \w \$\[\033[00m\] '
else
    PS1+='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;36m\] \w \$\[\033[00m\] '
fi
```

Depending on where you put it, might want to change `PS1+=` to `PS1=`.

Comment: What is the right place to put this in? How about /etc/profile.d/somename.sh ?

Comment: I think that'd be a reasonable place to try.  It's a question of "where else does it get set, and when".

Comment: `${EUID} == 0` should be `"$(id -u)" == 0`.

Comment: @AndyDalton Setting `EUID` for the `bash` process with `EUID=something bash` sets it _in_ the `bash` process.  Using as done here seems to be safe, but since it's a user-supplied value, using it *wrongly*, as in `[ $EUID -eq 0 ]` could lead to oddness, and potentially to a security hole. It is therefore _safer_ to use `"$( id -u )"`.

Comment: @AndyDalton There might be different patches for `bash` floating around. I'm using 4.4.23 on OpenBSD and `EUID=hello bash -c 'echo "$EUID"'` prints `hello`.

Comment: How to unset the default PS1 value? I have set the above in /etc/profile.d/terminal_color.sh file and sourced it. However when I do `echo $PS1` I see the following  `echo $PS1
[\u@\h \W]\$ \[\033[01;31m\]\h\[\033[01;36m\] \w \$\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;36m\] \w \$\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;36m\] \[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;36m\] \[\033[01;31m\] \w \$\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;36m\] \w \$\[\033[00m\]`

Comment: Did you try changing `+=` to `=`?  The `+=` appends to the variable; the `=` overwrites it.